# Java - modify file in parts

Tags: java, file, io, aes

I am working on an AES 256 bit File encryption tool. The way it works now is by:

reading an entire file into a String, 
encrypting the string, 
deleting the old file, then outputting the encrypted String into the old File object.

This works for small Files, but if you were to try to encrypt a Large file, such as one larger than the Heap Space java has access too, you receive errors.  Long story short, how can i read the file one MB at a time, as a String, encrypt that string, then write that MB to a temp file? This would allow for large files to be encrypted.

Comment: That is fundamentally tricky.  CBC makes that impossible, and ECB is not secure.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption_theory

Comment: You had better write the encrypted result to a _new file_, and if the new file is successfully created then delete the original file and rename the new file to the original one. This way you are guaranteed not to lose the original should writing to the new file fails.

Comment: thats a better idea, ill do that. but the main question is how to read the file to a string in parts

Comment: Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110153/java-reading-file-chunk-by-chunk

Comment: @DonutAvenger: instead of reading a file into memory, you can map it. This implies using nio, though.

Comment: Can you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11300687/1060037)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5623638/697630) might contain some info on NIO mapped buffers.

Comment: Yep, [memory mapped IO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) is what I'd recommend too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for temp files. Just use File Streams (FileInputStream and FileOutputStream). Streaming I/O was exactly created for processing long files in chunks. You can use FileReader/Writer if you want to read/write strings. [There is an example](http://www-users.york.ac.uk/~mal503/lore/pkencryption.htm):

```
  public void decrypt(File in, File out) throws IOException, InvalidKeyException {
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec);
    CipherInputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(in), aesCipher);
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(out);

    int i;
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    while((i=is.read(b))!=-1) {
            os.write(b, 0, i);
    }
```

Comment: I ended up using a FileReader to read in chars, then add them to a String. From there I encrypted that String and wrote it back. Doesnt seem very efficient though. Ill try taking a deeper look at your example.

Comment: Concatenating everything in memory defeats the very idea of streaming (in-block processing). Do you see that in.read(block) is interleaved with os.write(block)? Where do you see concatenation of the strings/blocks?

Comment: Please make sure you use the correct encryption mode, and don't forget to include an IV. Furthermore, don't forget that `CipherInputStream` has the unfortunate side effect of ignoring padding exceptions. Some kind of cryptographic checksum (MAC or HMAC) may also be a good idea.